# Regex (preg_match in php) : last groups in the output array don't work correctly

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

With this pattern:

```
(how is\s)?(the\s)?(weather)\s?((on)\s)?(today|tomorrow|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday|this week)?(\s(in)\s(.*)\s?(on)?\s?(today|tomorrow|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday|this week)?)?
```

This is what I'm  trying to capture

**Input** : `how is the weather on tuesday in vienna`

**output** :

```
array(10
0   =>  how is the weather on tuesday in vienna
1   =>  how is 
2   =>  the 
3   =>  weather
4   =>  on 
5   =>  on
6   =>  tuesday
7   =>   in vienna
8   =>  in
9   =>  vienna
)
```

Here, I can extract day and location from `array[6]` and `array[9]`

**Input** : `how is the weather in vienna on tuesday`

**output** :

```
array(10
0   =>  how is the weather in vienna on tuesday
1   =>  how is 
2   =>  the 
3   =>  weather
4   =>  
5   =>  
6   =>  
7   =>  in vienna on tuesday
8   =>  in
9   =>  vienna on tuesday
)
```

But here, the location and day are captured as a whole in `array[9]`. I want it to capture day and location in different elements. Is there anything wrong with the grouping in regex pattern?

Comment: I didn't understand your question can you give some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to achieve but I did a bit of modification and it **[`works`](https://regex101.com/r/pP1aV5/2)** giving the output..writing too long regex with so many optional groups is not too good

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with capturing timeframe and location in a grouping regex, but it would seem more valuable to capture the timeframe in one capture group, and the location in a separate capture group.  This way the values can be used immediately in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

I recommend using optional lookaheads to seek out and find the location or timeframe if they exist.

`^(?=(?:.*?on\s(today|tomorrow|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday|this week))?)(?=(?:.*?in\s([a-z]+))?)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- capture group 1 always gets the timeframe if it exists in the string
- capture group 2 always gets the location if it exists in the string
- allows the location and timeframe to appear in any order in the string

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/rN9hG2/1

**Sample text**

```
weather on sunday
weather on sunday in vienna
weather in vienna
weather in vienna on sunday
```

**Sample Matches**

```
[0][1] = sunday
[0][2] = 

[1][1] = sunday
[1][2] = vienna

[2][1] = 
[2][2] = vienna

[3][1] = sunday
[3][2] = vienna
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      on                       'on'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        today                    'today'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        tomorrow                 'tomorrow'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        sunday                   'sunday'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        monday                   'monday'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        tuesday                  'tuesday'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        wednesday                'wednesday'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        thursday                 'thursday'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        friday                   'friday'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        saturday                 'saturday'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        sunday                   'sunday'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        this week                'this week'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      in                       'in'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or
                                 more times (matching the most amount
                                 possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I'm still trying to understand the pattern though. Thank you so much

Comment: Think of it like this the `(?=.*?......)` plants its feet and uses binoculars to look ahead into the string to see if the string contains the desired text.

Comment: I modified it a bit to continue only if 'weather' is matched 
`^(?:(?:what\sis)?(?:\s?the\s?)?weather)(?=(?:.*?(?:on\s)?(today|tomorrow|sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday|this week))?)(?=(?:.*?in\s([a-z]+))?)` 


Now it captures the first part even though I asked it not to capture that part. I'm curious.

Comment: Capture group zero is always populated. When you added the `(?:....)` you are asking the regular expression engine to match a value which if it exists will be returned. I see that you added `?` to the end of them but this only means the string is optional.

Comment: If you only want to test the criteria if the word `weather` is included in the string without returning it then you'd wrap your new entire thing in a forward look ahead like `(?=....)` so it looks like `(?=(?:what\sis)?(?:\s?the\s?)?weather)`.

Comment: Of course this would fail to match the string `In vienna on saturday what will the weather be like`. So I'd just add `(?=(?:.*?weather)?)` which would look forward into the string to verify the word `weather` is contained in the string somewhere. This way the word `weather`, the time period, and location can appear in any order.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. So, positive lookahead will check if the string is present anywhere in it?

Comment: The regular expression engine will attempt to step through your source string one character at a time, then when it encounters a lookahead, the engine looks forward to see if the following string matches a pattern. [This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.htm) has a much better explanation that I can provide here.

Comment: It's a 404 but I'll find it.

Could you help me with another pattern?
`(?:(?:tell\s*me|explain)\s*(?:what|more\s*about)?)\s*(.*)(\s(?:is|are))?`

The problem here is that when there's **is** or  **are**  at the end, it always skips through the last group and captures that. 

So when I input **Explain what supernova is**, it captures **supernova is**.

Comment: You had several problems, with that expression. Namely greedy `.*`, oddly placed parenthesis. I think you really want to capture the word `supernova` and not include the word `is`.  Have a look at this https://regex101.com/r/sV9nN0/5

Answer (score 1):

### Capture all words

If I understood your question well, to capture those words then you can use a regex like this:

```
(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)(?:\s+(\w+)\s(\w+))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU9hU2/2)**

[image]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [3-10]  `weather`
2.  [11-13] `on`
3.  [14-20] `sunday`
MATCH 2
1.  [25-32] `weather`
2.  [33-35] `on`
3.  [36-42] `sunday`
4.  [43-45] `in`
5.  [46-52] `vienna`
MATCH 3
1.  [57-64] `weather`
2.  [65-67] `in`
3.  [68-74] `vienna`
MATCH 4
1.  [79-86] `weather`
2.  [87-89] `in`
3.  [90-96] `vienna`
4.  [97-99] `on`
5.  [100-106]   `sunday`
```

### Capture only your words in bold

On the other hand, if you want to capture your words in bold, then you can remove some capturing groups like below regex:

```
\w+\s+\w+\s+(\w+)(?:\s+\w+\s(\w+))?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU9hU2/3)**

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [14-20] `sunday`
MATCH 2
1.  [36-42] `sunday`
2.  [46-52] `vienna`
MATCH 3
1.  [68-74] `vienna`
MATCH 4
1.  [90-96] `vienna`
2.  [100-106]   `sunday`
```